# pass a callback method as parameter

Tags: c#

i want to pass a callback method as a parameter to a generalized method, but can't figure it out how to do it. i tried with `Func<IAsyncResult>` but it doesn't seem to be compatible.

```
public void webRequest(string apiName, string requestMethod, string requestData, Func<IAsyncResult> callback)
{
    ...
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
}
```

signature of callback is:

```
void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Don't say "doesn't work". Tell us what you expect, and what actually happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the parameter as `Action<T>` instead of `Func<T>`.

```
public void webRequest(string apiName, string requestMethod, string requestData, Action<IAsyncResult> callback)
```

`Func<IAsyncResult>` requires a function that takes no parameters and returns `IAsyncResult` instance:

> [***`Func<TResult>` Delegate***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)
>
> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the `TResult` parameter.

`Action<T>` does not return anything, just takes parameters:

> [***`Action<T>` Delegate***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)
>
> Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return
>   a value.

Comment: Look again at the code. The callback parameter is not used. And why do you recommend Action(T) here? Surely AsyncCallback is the desired type.

Answer (score 2):

BeginGetRequestStream expects a parameter of type AsyncCallback. So declare the callback parameter to be that type.

```
public void webRequest(string apiName, string requestMethod, 
    string requestData,  AsyncCallback callback)
{
    ...
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(callback, request);
}
```

You can then pass your callback method since it matches the required signature.

```
webRequest(apiName, requestMethod, requestData,
    GetRequestStreamCallback);
```